# Bootstrap popover scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid and on one of the columns, I have implemented Bootstrap popover.

So one of the columns would show "X number of people" link and on click of this link, I display a bootstrap popover with actual people names.

Below is my code;

```
$t
    .addClass('mySummaryData')
    .css({
        "white-space"   : "nowrap",
        "width"         : 380,
        "max-width"     : 380,
        "display"       : "block",
        "text-overflow" : "ellipsis",
        "overflow"      : "hidden"
    })
    .attr({
        'data-title':   'Title: ',
        'href'      :   "javascript: void(0)"
    })
    .popover({
            placement:  'left',
            html:       true,
            trigger:    'click',
            container:  'body',
            content:    _generatePopover()
     })
     .on('click.mypop', function(e){
            _hideMyPopover();
            $(this).popover("show");
     });
```

Now while I am able to get the popover on click of the link, since it is a grid, the user can also scroll through the grid data.

But if he does that while one of the popovers is open, the popover stays as it is and the grid scrolls making the popover seem a bit out of place.

How do I fix this?

Can I scroll the popover along with the grid ?

Comment: Not sure I understand as on the http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers page, you can also scroll and the popover stays relative to the correct element?

Comment: actually i am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and do not see any way on http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers

Comment: If you press red "Click to toggle popover" button on your link and then scroll the page the popover scrolls correctly with the button?  What are you meaning?

Comment: actually i have implemented the popover within a scrollable grid...so when i scroll through the grid, the popover does not scroll...

Comment: Can you perhaps show an example on bootply.com?